# vuejs - Safari browser navigation with Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, safari, vue-router

I have a VueJS app with vue-router and I stuck on problem with page which contains a Google map (standard realisation without vue plugins)

I use Safari and Google map breaks its browser navigation flow.

The flow is:

- 'Events list page'
- click on one event
- see 'One event page' (with Google map on it)
- click browser 'Back' button
- see the 'Events list page'
- click 'Forward' browser button
- see 'One event page'
- click 'Back' browser button
- **see 'One event page'** ('Forward' button is active and if I click on it I'll see the 'One event page' that I'm currently on)
- click 'Back' browser button again
- see the 'Events list page'

I have the last vue-router version (3.0.1) and I can't understand what's going on. This bug appears only in both mobile and desktop Safari (all versions) Please help =)

Comment: I am having the same problem.  history.back() would break with google map loaded.  Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add a google map script just before you're going to use it (example: on the page with a map)

```
function createPreconnectElement(src) {
  const preconnectElement = document.createElement('link');
  const headElement = document.querySelector('head');
  preconnectElement.rel = 'preconnect';
  preconnectElement.href = src;
  preconnectElement.crossOrigin = '';
  headElement.prepend(preconnectElement);
}

function init(elem) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!(window && window.google && window.google.maps)) {
      const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
      const appendToElement = elem || document.querySelector('head');
      const src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=beta&key=${API_KEY}`;
      scriptElement.src = src;
      scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
      createPreconnectElement(src);
      appendToElement.appendChild(scriptElement);
      scriptElement.onload = () => {
        resolve();
      }
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });
}
```

It solves the problem